# Increment var in callback node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is any possible to increment var licznik in this block of code?
I try sth like this, But always receives 0. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

```
rows.forEach(function(record) {
  var licznik = 0;
  var offer = manager.createOffer('76561198252553560');                       
  inventory.forEach(function(item) {
    if(licznik <= record.amount) {
      if(item.market_hash_name == record.real_name) {
        var asid = item.assetid;
        (function(licznik){
          connection.query('SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = \'' + asid + '\'', function(err, wiersze) {
            if (wiersze[0].wynik == 0) {
              var employee = {
                asset_id: asid,
                trans_id: record.tid
              };
              connection.query('INSERT INTO used SET ?', employee, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                offer.addMyItem(item);

                console.log(licznik);
                &licznik++;
              });
            }   
          }); 
        })(licznik);
      }
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment on your original question points out, I have no context for what this code is actually trying to accomplish. What I can tell you is that your callbacks supplied to `connection.query` are ***NOT*** fired on each iteration of the `forEach`. The whole reason `connection.query` takes a callback is because you don't know when the operation will complete. Node is designed to be asynchronous so all it does on each iteration of the `forEach` loop is begin the query. The callback supplied to the query could be invoked at any time which also means that a query that fired after another query could potentially fire its callback **before** the callback from the first query. It just depends on how long each query takes.

If you need `licznik` to be incremented on every iteration of the `forEach` then you need to increment it after your if statement.

```
rows.forEach(function(record) {
  var licznik = 0;
  var offer = manager.createOffer('76561198252553560');                       
  inventory.forEach(function(item) {
    if(licznik <= record.amount) {
      // .... omitted for brevity
    }
    licznik++; // <-- increment here, outside of the closure.
  });
});
```

Again, I have zero clue what you're actually trying to do with that variable so this may not solve your real problem, but that's the way to get it to increment in that loop.

PS - You may not be understanding that you actually have ***two*** `licznik` variables here. You create a new one when you wrap all your logic in a closure function like you did. If you change the variable declared at the top of your closure function you'll see that it's not the same variable as the one outside the closure function.

```
rows.forEach(function(record) {
  var licznik = 0;
  var offer = manager.createOffer('76561198252553560');                       
  inventory.forEach(function(item) {
    if(licznik <= record.amount) {
      if(item.market_hash_name == record.real_name) {
        var asid = item.assetid;
        (function(licznik2) { // <-- notice this is a new variable
          connection.query('SELECT count(id) as wynik FROM used where asset_id = \'' + asid + '\'', function(err, wiersze) {
            if (wiersze[0].wynik == 0) {
              var employee = {
                asset_id: asid,
                trans_id: record.tid
              };
              connection.query('INSERT INTO used SET ?', employee, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                offer.addMyItem(item);

                console.log(licznik2);
                licznik2++;
              });
            }   
          }); 
        })(licznik);
      }
    }
  });
});
```